Text recommendation in Shiny
I have the below example code which applies the filtering logic given in the text input.
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput("text", "Filter query")
      ),
      actionButton("apply", "apply")
    ),
    mainPanel(  
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df <- reactiveVal(iris)
  
  observeEvent(input$apply, {
    tryCatch({
      updated_df <- dplyr::filter(df(),
                                  !!rlang::parse_expr(input$text))
    }, error = function(e){
      req(FALSE)
    })
    
    
    df(updated_df)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    df()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

But I want to add one functionality like if any users type the logic wrong, it will suggest few filtering logic based on the nearest pattern the user given in the text box.
For example, if I write Species1 == "setosa" it should give me suggestion Species == "setosa" or Species = "setosa" system will suggest Species == "setosa". It should work for all columns and for all wrong filtering condition,
Is there any to achieve this?

Have a look at selectize input that will start searching for the options that partially match the string typed.

As mentioned, best to just have the search value i.e. select one or more of; 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'. I would add slider inputs to filter numeric columns

I would suggest to split that single input into several inputs instead:

a selectInput to indicate the column / feature (with choices = names(df))
keep the text input for the value only
an optional radio button for the conditions if it's not always "=="

Basically, unless the user is an expert, I would keep the syntax away from the input.
